# How to switch the engine off in Arena?

Tags: engines, software, arena

I use Arena. I want to input my game and create a pgn. But I have a problem, because if I make a move, the engine automatically makes a move as well. I want to make moves for white and for black.

I don't know how to switch the engine off.

Answer (score 3):

Version 3.5: Under the "List of Moves" Panel/TabControl there is a toolbar. The last component on the toolbar is the "Edit" button. The tooltip tells you when this button is down, the engines do not respond and you can enter your moves.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the `Engines` dropdown menu at the top of the screen, you can turn off the engine. This will allow you to make moves for both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn on the Edit button in the toolbar under the move list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but I can't make comments.  Neither of these two answers work for me.  I don't have an "edit" or "move" option on my toolbar, and when I when I do the "close engine" option, it only works for that one turn--i.e., the engine comes back on as soon as I make a move, so I would have to do it after every single move.  Like the original question, I can't find a way to do something that should be incredibly simple--just turn off the engine so I can play a 2-player game.  I have Arena 3.5

Update:  I didn't find an answer how to do this in Arena, but in another thread I found a user recommended [Jerry](https://github.com/asdfjkl/jerry/releases/tag/v.102) for this purpose, and it seems to work great.